# Inflection points of $\alpha(t)=(\sin(2t),\cos(3t))$

Tags: curves, parametric

I have to find the inflection points of the curve
$$\alpha(t)=(\sin(2t),\cos(3t)),\quad-\pi\leq t\leq\pi$$

The exercise explains itself that a inflection point is such that $\alpha'(t)$ and $\alpha''(t)$ are parallels.

Since
$$\alpha'(t)=(2\cos(2t),-3\sin(3t))$$
$$\alpha''(t)=(-4\sin(2t),-9\cos(3t))$$
then if $\alpha'$ and $\alpha''$ are parallels, the following cross product
$$\begin{vmatrix} i & j & k \\ 2\cos(2t) & -3\sin(3t) & 1 \\ -4\sin(2t) & -9\cos(3t) & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$
will be $\vec{0}$. So
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-3\sin(3t)+9\cos(3t)=0 \\
-4\sin(2t)-2\cos(2t)=0 \\
-18\cos(2t)\cos(3t)-12\sin(2t)\sin(3t)=0 
\end{array}\right.$$

I solved this system using Wolphram which says there are no solutions. However, when I see $\alpha$ plot, for me, there are 4 inflection points.

Comment: Should you not put $k$ component as zero instead of $1$? So it comes down to then just checking $-18\cos(2t)\cos(3t)-12\sin(2t)\sin(3t)=0$

Comment: @MathLover thank you, I didn't notice it.